# Flyway db | Liquibase equivalent for HIVE

Tags: hive, database-migration, liquibase, ddl, flyway

I used to manage my databases using Flyway, however we migrated to HDFS HIVE and I haven't seen anything like this, currently looking for recommendations

Comment: what about [this plugin](https://github.com/eselyavka/liquibase-impala)

Comment: this plugin looks good but Im not big fan of plugins, does you know a tool that comes with this functionality ?